# How to Merge A4 Size PDF with A8 size PDF in java using iText?

Tags: java, itext

I have a requirement to merge two pdfs sizes A8 and A4 as a single PDF. When we developed the merged PDF contains same size. could anyone please tell How to achieve this with different sizes having A8 and A4 sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `PdfWriter` class to merge documents goes against all the recommendations given in the *official* documentation, though there are *unofficial* examples that may have lured you into writing bad code. I hope that you understand that I find these bad examples even more annoying than you do.

Please take a look at Table 6.1 in [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). It gives you an overview showing when to use which class. In this case, you should use `PdfCopy`:

```
String[] files = { MovieLinks1.RESULT, MovieHistory.RESULT };
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
PdfReader reader;
int n;
// loop over the documents you want to concatenate
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
    // loop over the pages in that document
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
// step 5
document.close();
```

If you are using a recent version of iText, you can even use the `addDocument()` method in which case you don't need to loop over all the pages. You also need to take special care if forms are involved. There are several examples demonstrating the new functionality (dating from after the book was written) in the [Sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/).

Comment: Thanks Ashok, but how to merge with different sizes

Comment: Well, @Rajasekhar_b_1989, the fact that you ask this question proves that you didn't try the example as the example is doing exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think i have answered your question of merging two different size.. On my answer itself.